# Make 2019 Factorial Multiplication a perfect square

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

N is not a square number and consists of 2019 factorial multiplication as shown below:

$N=1!\times 2!\times 3!\cdots 2018!\times2019!$

> **At least how many factorial needed to be removed from the multiplication to make N a square number?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Theorem:** for any natural number $N$, the expression

> $\frac{(1!)(2!)(3!)\dots(4N)!}{(2N)!}$

is a perfect square.

**Proof:** by induction on $N$. The result is true for $N=1$, since

> $(1!)(3!)(4!)=144$ is a square.

Assume the result is true for $N=n-1$. Then we have, for $N=n$,

> $\frac{(1!)(2!)(3!)\dots(4n)!}{(2n)!}=\frac{(1!)(2!)(3!)\dots(4n-4)!}{(2n-2)!}\cdot\frac{(4n-3)!(4n-2)!(4n-1)!(4n)!}{(2n-1)(2n)}$.

The extra factor there is

> $\frac{(4n-3)!(4n-2)!(4n-1)!(4n)!}{(2n-1)(2n)}=\frac{(4n-2)^3(4n-1)^2(4n)}{(2n-1)(2n)}[(4n-3)!]^4=4(4n-2)^2(4n-1)^2[(4n-3)!]^4$

which is a perfect square. Thus the theorem is proved.

---

So we can remove

> four factorials to get a perfect square: namely $2019!,2018!,2017!,1008!$.

---

**An improvement**, thanks to @Neal in a comment: we can actually remove just

> three factorials. Starting from the perfect square we already found (with $2019!,2018!,2017!,1008!$ removed), let's re-multiply by $2018!$ and $2017!$ to get $2018$ times a perfect square. Then re-multiply by $1008!$ and divide by $1009!$ to get $2$ times a perfect square (since $2018=1009\times2$). Then finally remove $2!$; we now have a perfect square with just the three factorials $2019!,1009!,2!$ removed.

---

Can we do any better?

> Since 2017 is prime, we must remove an odd number of (either one or three of) the top three $2017!,2018!,2019!$ in order to get an even power of 2017 for a perfect square.

So if we remove just one factor, then it must be

> one of $2017!,2018!,2019!$, and that won't give a perfect square.

If we remove just two factors, then one of them must be

> one of those top three. But then the perfect square we found above by removing four factorials must be exactly this new perfect square *divided* by two of $2017!,2018!,2019!$ and *divided* by $1008!$ and *multiplied* by one other factorial. Again, that's not going to be a perfect square however we do it.

---

So the final answer is

> **three** factorials must be removed.

Comment: Your solution can actually be improved to 3. Note that 2017! * 2018! = 2018 * (2017!)^2, and 2018 = 2 * 1009, so we can remove 2!, 1009!, and 2019!.

Also see https://codeforces.com/contest/1622/problem/F

Comment: @Neal That's really neat, thank you! Sorry for slow response to your comment - I kept this open in a tab until I had time to come back and check the details.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts

> One reason the given product is not a square is that the prime number $2017$ occurs three times: in $2017!$ and $2018!$ and $2019!$
>
>  There needs to be an even number of occurrences of any prime, to enable a square root of their product to be possible.
>
>  This applies to every prime *factor* too.
>  For example when $N = 6$
>  $1! \times 2! \times 3! \times 4! \times 5! \times 6! = 2^{12} \times 3^5 \times 5^2$
>  So the product won't be a perfect square because of the odd power of $3$.
>
>  Going back to the three $2017$s, either all three or just one of them must be removed.
>  But if one: which one?
>  I am tempted to make a program which uses a recursive approach
>
> ```
>  Find highest prime factor with an odd power
>  Explore permutations of factorials removing 1,3,5 etc occurrences as a factor
>  For each one, repeat with next lowest odd-powered prime
>  If a solution is found, with fewest removals so far, record the series
> ```
>
> But it has to be later, if an answer is still needed.

Answer (score -3):

> Only factorial that would be perfect Square is 1! Therefore, from 2! To 2019! Have to be removed.

Comment: Example: $1! \times 3! \times 4! = 6 \times 24 = 144 = 12^2$.

Comment: Not my DV, some thoughts in an answer.